# What is the point of repeating the component word as naming convention?

Tags: angular, naming-conventions

Let us say we have a component with this structure, why we need to repeat the word "component" in the naming of component's files, since we already have it in our parent folder? I saw that this is the recommended [Angular 2 Style Guide](https://mgechev.github.io/angular2-style-guide/). Maybe it is easier to tell that this file is about a component rather than a service, if you include it in the name, but other than that is there any other benefit?

```
components
    ├── edit-profile.component.ts
    ├── edit-profile.component.html
    ├── edit-profile.component.css

directives
    ├── form-validator.directive.ts
    ├── form-validator.directive.spec.ts
    ├── tooltip.directive.ts

services
    └── authorization.service.ts
```

Answer (score 3):

> Maybe it is easier to tell that this file is about a component rather than a service, if you include it in the name, but other than that is there any other benefit?

That's what it is for.

If you create a feature than the related files should be kept together in a directory. To make them easy to distinguish when you have component(s), related directive(s), pipe(s), service(s) and maybe others in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you. For me the file name gets too long so I think I will skip it for now.

Comment: Sure, if it fits better with your project. The main point is to use rules consistently throughout your project. The official style guide is just what the Angular team agreed upon, for others its just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a way of naming convension, nothing else. Keeping ***component*** as suffix in each file that belongs to a component is just to tell the developer that hey you, this file is related to a component named *'edit-profile'*. file extensions are there to tell you that what kind of file it is for that particular component.

If you want to know that if this naming convention envolves in application building-compiling tasks, then NO, **it doesn't**.